# where are hibernate-orm-modules for wildfly 12 and 13?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-12

following [this guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html) I wanted to update hibernate on my wildfly 12 and 13 instances as I used to do before on 11. However [the search on maven central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-orm-modules%22) displays only modules for wildfly 10 and 11. Where are the modules for 12 and 13? where they moved to another maven repo or renamed maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you trying to upgrade to?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins 5.2.17.Final

Comment: That would be downgrading Hibernate. WildFly 13 ships with 5.5.8.Final and 5.10.1.Final. Is there a reason you'd need to downgrade?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins according to http://hibernate.org/orm/ the latest **stable** is 5.3 series (5.3.1.Final exactly), so if wildfly 12 or 13 is indeed using the unstable versions that you mentioned (which would be quite surprising) then the obvious reason is that I want to use a stable version. Now I need to 5.2.17.Final not 5.3.1.Final becuase I'm considering migrating some apps from wildfly-11 which use 5.2.17.Final and I don't want to update to 5.3.1.Final at this time as my dao submodule is shared between several other projects and I don't have resources at the moment to migrate them all.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins there are you sure about the version numbers you provided? https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm does not have branches for 5.10 nor for 5.5. master is 5.3 series at the moment...

Comment: I'm sorry. I looked at the version for Hibernate Search ORM which is 5.5.8.Final. For Hibernate ORM (core) it is indeed 5.3.1.Final if you use the EE 8 preview mode. Otherwise it's Hibernate 5.1.14.Final.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins ah yes: it explains a lot ;)  btw: could you please tell me how to check which version is included by default in wildfly? when I browse `modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate` subfolder nothing is there (only "empty slots" for 4.1, 4.3 and 5.0 series containing only `module.xml` file), so it must be somewhere else, right?

Comment: Honestly I just did `find $JBOSS_HOME/modules -name "hibernate*"` and looked for the path and version extension on the JAR :)

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins ah yes: I'm an idiot ;) thx!  (wildfly-12 has 5.1.10.Final btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they've been renamed and re-packaged in a different way (as a feature pack)
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html